# ¿Cómo hacer una caminata random?

Tags: java, loops, random

Necesito hacer un método que lleve a cabo una serie de pasos de una caminata random en una dimensión, comienza en la posición 0 y en cada paso incrementa o decrementa la posición en 1 de manera aleatoria hasta que la posición final sea 3 o -3.

**Código desarrollado:**

```
public static void randomWalk (){
    int a=0;
    int max=a;
    int b;
    
    Random rand = new Random();

    do { 
        b= rand.nextInt (2)-1; 
        if ((b<0)||(b>0)){
            a=a+b;
            System.out.println ("position " + a);
        }
    }
    while ((a<3)&&(a>-3));
}
```

Pero al ejecutar muestra siempre la secuencia:

> position -1
>
> position -2
>
> position -3

Comment: pero si ya sabes la secuencia, para que usar random?

Comment: no entiendo tu comentario?  esa es la secuencia que resulta cuando ejecuto el programa,

Comment: quieres esta secuencia? -3,-2,-1,1,2,3?

Comment: no, quiero que desde cero, se empieza a sumar o restar de manera random 1, hasta que me salga un -3 o un 3 algo como esto :                                  

position = 1

position = 0

position = –1

position = –2

position = –1

position = –2

position = –3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(-1, 2);` para establecer el rango de -1 a 1, y que puedas restar y sumar con ese monto, de acuerdo al rango se generara los numero randomicos que necesitas.

para que solamente obtenga `1 y -1` fije  nextInt(min, max no incluyente), es decir que el **maximo sera 2-1=1**.

```
    import java.lang.Math; // headers MUST be above the first class
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

// one class needs to have a main() method
public class HelloWorld
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {


   int a=0;
   int max=a;
   int b;

   do { 
   b = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(-1,2);
   System.out.println (b);
     if ((b<0)||(b>0)){
   a=a+b;
   System.out.println ("position " + a);
   }
   }
   while ((a<3)&&(a>-3));

   }

}
```

Comment: si, funciona pero no entiendo para que es la variable max

Answer (score 1):

Usando `SecureRandom` podrías simplemente usar `nextBoolean` con un ternario para incrementar o decrementar la posición. `max` determina la distancia máxima al punto cero, lo podemos comprobar con el método `Math.abs(int i)`. Así el código queda conciso y sin pasos sin cambio.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class Caminante implements Runnable{

    int pos=0;
    int max =3;
    SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        do{
            pos += (sr.nextBoolean()) ? 1 : -1;
            System.out.println(String.format("pos: %d", pos));
        }while(Math.abs(pos)<max);
        System.out.println("terminado!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Caminante().run();
    }
}
```

alternativamente se podría generar un `int` de 0 o 1 y usar la formula:

```
pos += sr.nextInt(2)*2 -1;
```